# hook_form_alter add field after submit button to exposed view

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I'm trying to add a field that would be displayed after the submit button in the rendered HTML in my hook_form_alter.

e.g.

```
$form['include_card'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Include gift card'),
  '#weight' => 25,
];
```

Weight doesn't seem to have any bearing on it.  How would you set that up?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but I believe there's a *#sorted* key somewhere in the *$form* array. You need to make sure it's set to false. If it's set to true, the form has already been sorted and it won't be re-sorted, i.e. you can add new fields or adjust existing weights and the weights will be ignored. If you set it to false, the form will be re-sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submit button will likely be inside an [Actions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Actions.php/class/Actions/9.0.x) element, which has a default weight of 100.

You could add your field to the actions element:

```
$form['actions']['include_card'] = ...
```

At which point the weight of `include_card` will be relative to the buttons/etc that are inside the actions element (and 25 will probably work).

Another option would be to position your element directly after the actions:

```
$form['include_card'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Include gift card'),
  '#weight' => $form['actions']['#weight'] + 1,
];
```